# Telebot and Telethon libraries connection

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

Good day!
I'm interested in combining telegram bot with some functions of telethon libraries (to get all the users of any chat I choose). My code starts the bot with the command /send, then asks for a phone number, sends a request code to the telegram account and then it should sign in as this user and collect the dialogs. Now it reads the phone and sends a code. However, it stops when I type in the code I received from telegram and my mobile telegram app crashes (I have to log out and sign in again)

```
from telethon import TelegramClient                            
from telebot import TeleBot                                     
import asyncio                                                  

api_id = *******
api_hash = '******'
client=TelegramClient('anon', api_id, api_hash)                 

bot_token='********'
bot = TeleBot(token:=bot_token)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['send'])                         # Parser of users
def send_adv(message): 
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Enter your phone number')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_phone)

def get_phone(message):

    phone=message.text                                          

    use_async(1, phone, None)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Enter your code')

    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, lambda m: get_code(m, phone))
                                                            
def get_code(message, phone_num):

    chat=message.chat.id
    code=message.text
    print(message.text)
   
    use_async(2, phone_num, code)

    bot.send_message(chat, 'Getting your dialogs')

    dial=use_async(3, None, None)

    bot.delete_message(chat, message.id+1)

    dials=dial[0]
    dial=dial[1:]

    bot.send_message(chat, dials)
    bot.send_message(chat, "Which dialogs users should I parse")

    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, lambda m: choose_dial(m, dialogs:=dial))        
                                                            
def choose_dial(message, dialogs):

    num=message.text

    if num>len(dialogs) or isinstance(num, int)==False:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Check the dialog number')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, lambda m: choose_dial(m, dialogs))  
        return None 

    users=use_async(4, dialogs, num)
    for user in users:
        print(user)

async def async_fun(i, phone_num, code_pas):                    # Async functions I call throughout the code

    if i==1:
        await client.connect()                                  # Connecting to Telegram
        await client.sign_in (phone_num)                        # Send code request
        return None

    elif i==2:                                                  
        if client.is_connected==False:
            await client.connect()                              # Connecting to Telegram if it hasn't been
        await client.sign_in(phone_num, code_pas)               # Signing in
        return None
#**
```

Here I think I've got a problem but I can't find exact string which causes it**

```
    elif i==3:                                                  # Collecting dialogs names
        j=1
        dials=''
        dial=[]
        async for dialog in client.iter_dialogs():
            if dialog.is_group==True:                           
                dials+=(str(j)+' - '+dialog.name+"\n")          # String of dialogs for a bot message
                dial.append(dialog.id)                          # an array of dialog names
                j+=1
        return dial.insert(0, dials)

    elif i==4:
        users=[]
        async for user in client.iter_participants(phone_num[code_pas-1]):
            if user.id!="":
                users.append (user.id)
        return users

    else:                                                      
        await client.log_out()                                  # Logging out
        await client.disconnect()                               # Disconnecting from Telegram
        return None

def use_async(i, phone_num, code_pas):                          # ПGetting the results of an asynchronous function by its index
     loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()                                                          
     asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)                                
     coroutine = async_fun(i, phone_num, code_pas)               # Getting the result of a function
     loop.run_until_complete(coroutine)                          # Stopping the process

bot.polling()`
```

Comment: All tags have a description. Please read them before using the tag ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your `use_async` function creates a new event loop every time it is called. Telethon needs to reuse the same loop once the connection was established or it won't work correctly. It's not clear to me that this is the error you're facing but it is something you should fix.

The simplest way to correct this mistake is by having a single `async def main()` and doing all your work from within it (including calling functions which are not `async`).

I can't say much about "mobile telegram app crashes", but you may run into issues by sending Telegram's OTP over Telegram itself, and I don't know the exact rules regarding that so I can't offer more help there.

Comment: I see your point but I can't find a way to use next_step_handler to read the message with code